# Quarkus HTTP authentication logout

Tags: quarkus

I'm currently developping an application with Quarkus usig an http form authentication. After reading "Form based authentication" page (https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication) I'm facing an issue with the logout stage. The documentation does not mention any option to logout the current session.

As Quarkus internally uses Vert.x, I tried the following:

```
@Path("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @LoggerName("AuthController")
    Logger log;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.http.auth.form.cookie-name")
    String COOKIE_NAME;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.http.auth.form.location-cookie")
    String REDIRECT_COOKIE_NAME;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.http.auth.form.login-page")
    String LOGIN_PAGE;

    @GET
    @Path("/logout")
    public void logout(@Context RoutingContext ctx) {
        var c1 = ctx.removeCookie(COOKIE_NAME);
        var c2 = ctx.removeCookie(REDIRECT_COOKIE_NAME);
        log.info(String.format("c1 = %s, c2 = %s", c1.getName(), c2.getName()));
        ctx.redirect(LOGIN_PAGE);
    }
}
```

This does not works like expected. The log.info logs well (`[AuthController] (executor-thread-0) c1 = MyCookieName, c2 = quarkus-redirect-location`) and the redirection works fine. However the session persists.

How can i fixed it ?

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several research and tries, a solution I found is to invalidate the cookie with Javascript using:

```
document.cookie = "MyCookieName=; Max-Age=0";
```

This invalidate the cookie and redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, something like this seems to work (with `resteasy-reactive`):

```
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServerResponse;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestResponse;

@Path("/logout")
public class UserLogout {

   @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.http.auth.form.cookie-name")
   String cookieName;

   @Inject
   UriInfo uriInfo;

   @POST
   public RestResponse<Object> logout(HttpServerResponse response) {
      URI loginUri = uriInfo.getRequestUriBuilder().replacePath("/login").build();
      // Note that we set invalidate=true to expire the cookie
      response.removeCookie(cookieName, true);
      return RestResponse.seeOther(loginUri);
   }
```

}

PS. `io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext.removeCookie(String, boolean)` is deprecated and `@Context` is unnecessary in `resteasy-reactive`.